# react-native footer appears above keyboard on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native-base

I have this react-navigation TabNavigator component and the problem is when the form input is focused, the TabNavigator footer appears on top of keyboard and it happens only on Android. How to solve this ? I have tried adding styles such as 
 position: 'absolute',
 bottom: 0
in tabBarOptions.
Here is my TabNavigator

```
export const AuthTaber = TabNavigator(
  {
    Signin: { screen: Signin },
    Signup: { screen: Signup }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    lazy: true,
    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return(
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab style={Style.bgBlack}>
            <Button
              vertical
              // active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Signin')}
              >
              <Text style={Style.white}>Sign In</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              // active={props.navigationState.index === 1}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}
              >
              <Text style={Style.white}>Sign Up</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: see react-navigation issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/721

Answer (score 4):

Just add this

```
<activity
.....
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"

.....
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use View instead of footer and native-base

```
   <View style={Style.bgBlack}>    // Do not have width and height in style
      <Button
        vertical
        // active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Signin")}
      >
        <Text style={Style.white}>Sign In</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button
        vertical
        // active={props.navigationState.index === 1}
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}
      >
        <Text style={Style.white}>Sign Up</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
```